# Css prevent child from expanding parent

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I have a container with unknown width and two children.

I want the first child to determine the width of the container.

I want the second child to wrap inside the container.

How can I do this using e.g. flexbox?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">this determines the container width</div>
  <div class="second"> if this is too long, it wraps around</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

first you will have to add `display: inline-block` to your container because div by default have `display: block` which takes 100% width

next set `.container` width to `max-content` so it will take only as many space as it needs to fit whole content and with `.first` that by default have `display: block` this element will set width for `.container`

lastly set `max-width: fit-content` on your `.second` element so it will "fit" inside container.

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    width: max-content;
}
.second {
    max-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">this determines the container width</div>
    <div class="second">asd asd if this is too long, it wraps around asd asd</div>
</div>
```